# PHP parando de insertar na tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma aplicação que funciona com log de atividades do facebook, tenho 150 paginas em monitoramento, e faço a inserção diária dessas linhas:

- Post
- Comment
- Reply
- Likes
- Shares

Ele tem atingido 500 mil registros em 2 horas no máximo, só que ai vem o problema, antes eu trabalhava regulando o tempo no bot, daí tirei essa limitação, o banco de dados recebe até um certo ponto e continua funcional mas não insere, só após reiniciar o vps ele insere uma grande quantidade de registros mesmo sem o bot ativo.

Coloquei eventos para limpeza de log interno(par não requisitar a mesma coisa da api), e para limpar os logs do mysql (flush logs & purge binários)
Uso PHP 5.4 + mariadb

Desde já agradeço qualquer contribuição

Comment: Não da para eu saber muito com o que vc colocou, se tiver mais detalhes melhor, mas vamos la, imagino que seja memória, talvez esteja com algum loop muito grande ai? Generators do php já me ajudou muito quanto a memória em loops com muitos dados, mas só para php 5.5+

Comment: Sim, tenho um loop infinito captando 24 horas, quando não há nada atual ele começa a atualizar os antigos e tal. Estou no momento com 24 GB de RAM e não usa nem 1/3. Quando usava no Debian os bots funcionavam 24 horas sem interrupção, ja no Centos ele vai mais rápido, mas ocorre esse problema. vou dar uma olhada nessa função que mencionou. Mas acredito que talvez seja alguma variável do php, embora tenha colocado execution e insert com -1. Ele inserta uns 10 minutos apenas, mas algumas tabelas não passam por esse problema. Nos logs não aparece nada :/ nem do apache nem do mysql

Comment: timeout então, será que pode ser, por vc dizer que ele para depois de 10 minutos...

Comment: sim, exatamente! No phpinfo mostra o php.ini que fiz a modificação para tempo de execução e insert inilimitado, haveria alguma outra variável para modificar? Esse tipo de intermitência é complicado de debugar :/ pq tipo hj a tarde o problema foi menos recorrente e o tempo de 10 minutos não foi regra...